# Return value of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a portion of code that is like the following:

[image]

I am trying to return the cell directly below the cell that is "A" but I do not want to have any whitespace in between the cells.

I tried using `=IF(A1="A",OFFSET(A1,1,0))` but this adds "FALSE" in between the cells where this is not true like so:

[image]

How do I remove the whitespace using a formula only to get the output of:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This standard formula will collect the values directly under each cell containing *A*.

[image]

Use this in B1 `=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(INDEX(ROW(A:A)+(A:A<>"A")*1E+99,,),ROW(1:1))+1),"")` and fill down as necessary.

The `IFERROR` return empty strings when it runs out of values to return. These are *not* the same as truly blank cells.

Although entered as a standard formula, this does use *array processing* and if you find calculation lag a problem pare down the full column range references to something closer to what the extents of your data represent.

Comment: It is okay if it returns empty strings. Thank you, this was a perfect solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to avoid VBA, you can perform this calculation using the following formulas, or some variant thereof:

[image]

The output will look like the following for the example you provided:

[image: Result]